Displace with repeat zone in geo nodes
Let's say you want multiple blocks of Swiss cheese. But you don't want the holes in the same place.
I thought to iterate the W of a 4D voronoi texture, but it won't iterate.



From the documentation of the Instance on Points node, Instance Index is "only used when Pick Instances is true". Furthermore, the Repeat zone is not making multiple instances, but a single Mesh.

Ah okay that explains a lot thank you!

@StefLAncien: i think your comment is not completely true... as you can see in my answer. Or did you mean "his special repeat zone"?

@Chris: I was talking about the repeat zone shown in the figure attached to the question, not generally speaking as your proposal clearly demonstrate.

@StefLAncien: that why i added "his special repeat zone" - it could be misunderstood ;) maybe "your repeat zone" would have been a bit clearer ;)

you nearly made it, just add these nodes:

so by transforming your geometry to instance and join that geometry, you will have instances, you can use:

Note: don't forget to uncheck "pick instance"

Woah thank you very much! :)

you are welcome
